# ModalPopupExtender not showing anything

Tags: c#, .net, ajax

Here is the relevant part of the aspx file:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>


        <div id="containerForTopButtonsCenter">
            <telerik:RadButton ID="bt_addNewSnpAtTop" runat="server" Text="Add New SNP" AutoPostBack="false" UseSubmitBehavior="false" OnClientClicked="clickedToCreateNewSNP" OnClick="bt_addNewSnpAtTop_Click" />            
        </div>
<atk:ModalPopupExtender ID="NewSnpsModalExtender" runat="server"
        TargetControlID="bt_addNewSnpAtTop"
        PopupControlID="NewSnpsPopupWindow"
        BackgroundCssClass="NewSnpsBackground"
        OkControlID="NewSnpsOk"
        CancelControlID="NewSnpsCancel"
        DropShadow="true">
    </atk:ModalPopupExtender>
    <asp:Panel ID="NewSnpsPopupWindow" runat="server">
        Hello! This is the Modal.
    </asp:Panel>
```

When I click on the bt_addNewSnpAtTop button, no modal pops up. Also, the panel control NewSnpsPopupWindow shows up on the parent page (I was hoping that it would house the content displayed in the modal)...

All help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the reason is related to your button also having onclick and onclientclick events.

In your OnClick event try:

```
bt_addNewSnpAtTop_Click(object sender, eventargs e)
{
    //Other Code

    NewSnpsModalExtender.Show();
}
```